# Keeping track of DB changes at client side

Tags: sql-server

We have many clients and people at client side modify the data stored in Sql server database. This modification most of the time brings unpleasant situation as they forget  to make appropriate changes in dependent tables. Moreover, nobody admit that they have modified the data.

Is there a way using which i can keep track of what data changed? who changed it? when it changed?

Anyone has idea, please let me know.

Comment: You've asked 12 questions and accepted none. You might want to go accept some answers if you expect people to help you more.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new table to log changes and log the changes by creating trigger(s) for particular database artifacts(tables)

More Info : [Audit Changes to SQL Server data](http://web.archive.org/web/20071006100909/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com:80/how-do-i-audit-changes-to-sql-server-data.html)

Comment: Assuming the client-side has some sort of authentication for each user involved or you can change the application to pass through some sort of information to identify the person modifying data, i agree with DSharper.